# Use Dynamic Locale in Duetds Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker

The Duetds Datepicker ([https://github.com/duetds/date-picker](https://stackoverflow.com)) code used in vue js is :

```
<template>
  <div class="v-datepicker" :class="classes">
    <duet-date-picker
      class="v-datepicker__input"
      identifier="date"
      ref="duetDatePicker"
      :localization.prop="localisedContent"
      :value="value ? formatInputDate(value) : null"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { format, parse, parseISO } from 'date-fns';
  import VInput from './VInput';

  export default {
    props: {
      value: {
        validator: prop => prop instanceof Date || prop === null,
        required: true,
      },
      content: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
        default: () => {},
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      if (this.calendarEnabled) {
        this.setDateFormat();
      }
    },
    computed: {
      localisedContent() {
        return {
          buttonLabel: "Choose date",
    dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    locale: "en-US",
        };
      },
      classes() {
        return {
          'v-datepicker--error': this.error,
        };
      },
    },
    methods: {
      setDateFormat() {
        const LOCALE = this.content.locale;
        const DATE_FORMAT_REGEX = this.getDateFormatRegex();
        this.$refs.duetDatePicker.dateAdapter = {
          // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
          parse(value = '', createDate) {
            const matches = value.match(DATE_FORMAT_REGEX);
            if (matches) {
              return createDate(matches[3], matches[2], matches[1]);
            }
          },
          format(date) {
            const day = (`0${date.getDate()}`).slice(-2);
            const month = (`0${date.getMonth() + 1}`).slice(-2);
            const year = date.getFullYear();

            switch (LOCALE) {
            case 'en-US':
              return `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
            default:
              return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
            }
          },
        };
      },
      getDateFormatRegex() {
        return /^(\d{1,2})[.\-/](\d{1,2})[.\-/](\d{4})$/;
      },
    },
    components: {
      VInput,
    },
  };
</script>
```

Here in this code date-format is handled only for locale `en-US` in `setDateFormat` method but how can I handle different date formats based on different locales? for example if `en-GB` is passed date-format should come as DMY. Link for reference https://github.com/duetds/date-picker